# control to display docx (word files) and xls (excel files ) inside vb.net form

Tags: vb.net

which are the control used to display word files and excel sheets inside vb.net forms ?
(i have already added reference lib.)

Platform: Vb.net (framework : 3.5)
language : visual basic

Comment: What "reference lib" have you added? Are you using winforms or WPF? I am asking as there is no such thing as vb.net forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to display word and excel files in Visual Basic using Microsoft's WebBrowser control.  You can find more information and example code here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243058

- Jeff